# Okay that TV wobbles when articulating wall mount is extended?

Tags: walls, structural, television, mount

I have a TV securely (lag screws into studs) mounted to the wall with an extending/articulating wall mount. We don't move it around, the TV remains in fixed position, about 20" away from the wall. However, I recently noticed the TV wobbles if touched or bumped even slightly on either end, furthest away from the centre. The wall mount is quite secure, and I've tightened up all the adjustable joints, it's just that the TV itself can wobble and vibrate since the whole thing is cantilevered out. Now that we have a toddler, I'm wondering if this is a safety concern. I cannot find any advice or guidance about adding extra support to a wall mounted TV, I only see people advocating for safety straps, etc. for TVs that are free-standing.

So my main question is this: is it okay that a wall-mounted TV wobbles a bit when touched? How much is too much? Part of me says it's fine, it's securely mounted, and cantilevered things like that will always wobble (like the tip of an airplane's wing). But the other part of me is, well, a worried dad.

I'm thinking the easiest way to remedy this would be to fasten a vertical support from the bottom of TV or the mount itself straight down to floor. That kinda ruins the whole "floating TV" look, though.

Answer (score 4):

If the TV weighs less than or equal to what the mount is rated for, it should be fine.

However.

You could upgrade to a sturdier mount rated for yet more weight, (increasing the safety factor) and perhaps of a more robust design (*i.e.*, mounts with two sets of arms holding the TV, rather than a single arm) if it would provide "worried parent peace of mind" (albeit at some cost.)

[image: Twin Arm Mount image from Monoprice. I have bought things from them, but no other association / no endorsement intended]

Comment: I would venture to say that even a 30 lb TV on a 100 lb rated mount, when extended 20" from the wall, will have _some_ wobble. At our church, we have a camera on a mount on a wall. The mount is _explicitly_ designed for _this_ camera (from the same mfgr) and extends as a platform about 6" from the wall. When someone walks up the stairs behind the wall, the camera will exhibit a bit of vibration _because the mount wobbles_. It's just gonna happen...

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what's occurring, simply due to the extension away from the wall. I have a double-arm mount - like what's depicted above in @Ecnerwal's answer - holding a TV that's lighter than the mount's rating, but the TV still wobbles when touched.